# 2-level group by for objects in an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Good day SO Community,

I would like to ask for your help in creating the correct aggregation pipeline for sample data:

```
[
  {
    "group": "A",
    "subgroup": "A1",
    "name": "Abby"
  },
  {
    "group": "A",
    "subgroup": "A2",
    "name": "Andy"
  },
  {
    "group": "A",
    "subgroup": "A2",
    "name": "Amber"
  },
  {
    "group": "B",
    "subgroup": "B1",
    "name": "Bart"
  }
]
```

I want to group by `group` first, then for each group, group by `subgroup`.

The `names` will also go to their respective subgroup and the `count` is showing the actual count.

My expected output is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "B",
    "count": 1,
    "subgroup": [
      {
        "_id": "B1",
        "count": 1,
        "names": ["Bart"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "A",
    "count": 3,
    "subgroup": [
      {
        "_id": "A1",
        "count": 1,
        "names":[ "Abby"]
      },
      {
        "_id": "A2",
        "count": 2,
        "names": ["Amber", "Andy"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried this pipeline but it's not grouping the `subgroup`s.

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$group",
    "subgroup": {
      "$addToSet": {
        "_id": "$subgroup",
        "name": "$name",
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}
```

The aggregation pipeline and actual output can be seen in the playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/MO1fCf21Rez

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `group` and `subgroup`. Perform count and add `name` into `names` array.
2. `$group` - Group by `group`. Perform total count and add the object for `subgroup` into `subgroup` array.

```
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        group: "$group",
        subgroup: "$subgroup"
      },
      names: {
        $push: "$name"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.group",
      "subgroup": {
        $addToSet: {
          "_id": "$_id.subgroup",
          "names": "$names",
          count: "$count"
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: "$count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cscAOft9JHb)

Comment: Sorry my bad. The last `$group` stage for the `count` field should be: `count: { $sum: "$count" }` in order to sum all `count`.